# RowSourceType user-defined function - "code" argument constants

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working through some textbook examples, and one shows that a user-defined function can be used to fill a combo or list box by calling a user-defined function from the RowSourceType property of the control.

The user defined function must accept specific inputs, as Access will call the function several times while filling in the list or combo box. You can see the names of the constants [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.rowsourcetype).

Then when I open a certain form, the following function will be called by the RowSourceType property of control on that form.

```
Function listEndDates(fld As Control, id As Variant, row As Variant, col As Variant, code As Variant) As Variant
    Debug.Print code 'I inserted this so I could see what constants Access was giving the function
    Dim integerOffset As Integer
    
    Select Case code
        Case acLBInitialize
            listEndDates = True
        Case acLBOpen
            listEndDates = Timer
        Case acLBGetRowCount
            listEndDates = 11
        Case acLBGetColumnCount
            listEndDates = 1
        Case acLBGetColumnWidth
            listEndDates = -1
        Case acLBGetValue
            integerOffset = Abs((8 - Weekday(Now)) Mod 7)
            listEndDates = Format(((Now() + integerOffset) - 35) _
       + 7 * row, "MM/DD/YYYY")
    End Select
    
End Function
```

This produces the following output in the immediate window, and I've typed in the corresponding constant names. **But what is MS Access doing with the constant 2?**

```
 0 acLBInitialize

 2
 1 acLBOpen
 4 acLBGetColumnCount
 5 acLBGetColumnWidth
 5 acLBGetColumnWidth
 3 acLBGetRowCount

 6 acLBGetValue
 7 acLBGetFormat
```

I tried looking at the VBA documentation and also in the object browser showing hidden members. There is no constant in Access.Constants that has a value of 2.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, and the answer is, that it is for internal use only - as quoted here in my project [VBA.Callback](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Callback) at **GitHub** in this paragraph:

[2. Dynamic formatting](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Callback#2-dynamic-formatting)

> Apparently, there is no value of 2 in use, thus no constant for this
> value exists. This is not so, however, only is the value for internal
> use only - to check for the RowSource type of the control. Running
> some tests will reveal, that calling a callback function later with a
> value of 2 for the argument Code "does nothing".

> This opens an option to call the function to do "something else" than
> it otherwise is supposed to do, and this "something else" could be to
> reconfigure the callback function.

To set this up, a named constant is introduced for the purpose:

```vb
2 acLBOpenAsVariant
```

**Addendum**

To return more than one column, use the `Column` variable as shown here:

[Improved Example](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Callback#improved-example)

where the first column returns the true date value and the second the formatted date for display:

```vb
Case acLBGetValue                       ' Get the data for each row.
    DayOfWeek = (FirstDayOfWeek + Row - 1) Mod DaysPerWeek + 1
    If Column = 0 Then
        ' Return weekday value.
        Value = DayOfWeek
    Else
        ' Return friendly name for display.
        Value = StrConv(WeekdayName(DayOfWeek, False, vbSunday), vbProperCase)
    End If
```

Comment: Is it possible to return multiple values from this user-defined function to make the listbox/combobox multi-column?

Comment: Yes, see extended answer, please.